# Не получается вызвать configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

Я работал с Hibernate, создал hibernate.cfg.xml в нужном каталоге, а именно src->main->resources, работаю в vs code с gradle.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property> <!-- BD Mane -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> <!-- DB Driver -->
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property> <!-- DB User -->
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property> <!-- DB Password -->
    
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> <!-- DB Dialect -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
    
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Далее у меня main класс `HibernateRunner`:

```
package app.src.main;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration;
  }
}
```

И сам gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

java{
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21;
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21;
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.4.4.Final'
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.2'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'

testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.2'

}
```

Ошибка:

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/69/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage/57cdddb0ee6064fc09d3b2c11202f375/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Makhmud_22351772/",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Project 'Makhmud_22351772' is missing required source folder: '_/project_hibernate/app/src'",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
},{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/69/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage/57cdddb0ee6064fc09d3b2c11202f375/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Makhmud_22351772/",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

Вторая ошибка:

```
[{
    "resource": "/D:/Makhmud/app/src/main/HibernateRunner.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "268435846",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The import org.hibernate cannot be resolved",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 21
},{
    "resource": "/D:/Makhmud/app/src/main/HibernateRunner.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "16777218",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Configuration cannot be resolved to a type",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 18
},{
    "resource": "/D:/Makhmud/app/src/main/HibernateRunner.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "1610612976",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error, insert \"( )\" to complete Expression",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 39,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 52
},{
    "resource": "/D:/Makhmud/app/src/main/HibernateRunner.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#10",
    "code": "16777218",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Configuration cannot be resolved to a type",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 39,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 52
}]
```

Comment: `Configuration configuration = new Configuration;` - круглые скобки забыли.

Comment: я пытался и так и как угодно все равно не работает она вообще не появляется когда пишешь лист похожих там вообще ничего